# Display search results on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-maps

At the moment the website is coded in PHP and results get pulled from a database using API url. The search result returns 10 items by default which needs to be plotted on the map.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
// Loading Domus API
$url_search = 'http://url/site/go/api/search';
$xml_search = @simplexml_load_file($url_search) or die ("no file loaded") ;
//Displaying latitude and longutude
$xml_search = json_decode($xml_search);
foreach($xml_search->property as $house) { 
    echo $lat = $house->address->latitude , $long = $house->address->longitude;
    };
```

?>

Then I have the JavaScripts

```
var locations = [

];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

But this does not work, of course.

Comment: It's fairly easy, check out the google maps API, specifically the playground part of it, they have examples with pretty much exactly what you want to do, eg: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#markers_v3

Comment: Thanks but how can I get my results displayed as this just shows random ones?

Comment: I'll write it into an answer for you, as it'll be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

To get the points on the map to the places you want, you'll need to determine the longitude/latitude of the places you want to plot. I'd suggest you use the Google Maps Geocoding API to figure this out for you, for example, lets use the Railway Station in County Beds, postcode MK401DR.

Feed that postcode to the Geocode API with the URL, like so

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=MK401DR,+UK&sensor=true

and you'll get a JSON array with address information, but most importantly for you under `"geometry"` you'll see it has given you the longitude/latitude position, eg:

```
"lat" : 52.1516477,
"lng" : -0.4437241
```

So for example, if you fed that long/lat into the Google API playground link i gave you (https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#markers_v3), like this

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.1516477, -0.4437241),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', addMarkers);

}

function addMarkers() {
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
  var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
  var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.1516477, -0.4437241);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });
}
```

​
you'll now have a map within the county of Bedfordshire with the train station (ish, you'll need to figure out which long/lat given to you by the geocode api is most accurate, the more of the address you feed the Geocode API, the more accurate the long/lat it'll give you) marked for you.

then you can add another marker by adding another

```
 var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng([latitude], [longitude]);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
 });
```

So you'll want to run through all of the addresses of the points you have, and obtain their longitude/latitude (if you don't have them already). Then you'll want to feed them into the Google Maps API javascript, and it'll plot the markers for you.

**edit:**

Very rough example of how to auto plot your points from PHP, to javascript, you would obviously need to include the rest of the Google Maps API js & relevant HTML container etc...

```
<?php
// array of properties
$properties = array(
  array('long' => '52.1516477', 'lat' => '-0.4437241'),
  array('long' => '52.1526477', 'lat' => '-0.4438241'),
  array('long' => '52.1536477', 'lat' => '-0.4439241'),
  array('long' => '52.1546477', 'lat' => '-0.4439641'),
)
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var properties_array = <?php echo json_encode($properties)?>;

      function plot_map_points() {
          $.each(properties_array, function(index, value) {
              var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(value['lat'], value['long']);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latLng,
                  map: map
              });
          });
      }
      plot_map_points();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I have a similar out on my details page for each property which is easy enough as the long and lat get populated by php query. Would I be able to autopopulate them using something like this <?php foreach($xml_search as $property) { 
if(isset($property->id)) {
 ?>

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest using PHP to `json_encode()` your array of your properties, and then output that either straight into your javascript, or retrieve it via AJAX which would be an even better solution, & then json decode it. I would then loop through your json array using forEach (if your are using plain javascript) or .each() (if you are using jQuery) and add each map point that way.

Comment: Sorry, my understanding of jquery and php is limited!

Comment: No worries, I'll try to write you a quick example of what I mean.

Comment: Usually, yes, but for this problem I think it would take too wayyy too much time to go through your code and alter it to what I'm referring to, and I think by the end of it all it wouldn't be your code anymore!! I'd suggest just reading into the function names I've mentioned and the example I've given. There will be plenty of other examples on Google doing what I've shown, and with a bit of searching you can probably find a much better example that'll be doing something you can use much more easily!

Comment: MLeFevre, thanks! I could use "foreach" function couldn't I, as all the values get pulled down from an API url?

Comment: @MLeFevre brilliant stuff mate. I wonder why your answer was never accepted by author. and you didnt receive any thumbsup on this. Thanks for this nice and detailed stuff. Worked like a charm.